# Is there a way to add default value for a parameter while creating a user defined function using CREATE FUNCTION command?

Tags: sql, oracle, clickhouse

I want to create the ClickHouse equivalent of the following Oracle function, if desired precision is defined in the function input, result is generated with rounding to desired number of digits, if not result is generated without rounding.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PercentTEST
  (p_divisor IN number, p_denom IN number, p_round IN number default -1, p_zeroreject IN number default null)
  return number
is
 vReject NUMBER;
begin
  if p_denom is NULL then
    return null;
  elsif p_denom = 0 then
    return p_zeroreject;
  end if;
  vReject:=100*p_divisor/p_denom;
  IF p_round <> -1 THEN
    vReject:=round(vReject,p_round);
  END IF;
  return vReject;
end;
```

I couldn't find any info in official ClickHouse docs for the equivalent of default keyword in Oracle,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PercentTEST on cluster 'mycluster' AS (num, denom, precision DEFAULT -1) -> if(isFinite(num / denom), round((100 * num) / denom, precision), NULL)
```

returns

Code: 62. DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 86 ('DEFAULT'): DEFAULT -1) -> if(isFinite(num / denom), round((100 * num) / denom, precision), NULL). Expected one of: token, Dot, Comma, ClosingRoundBracket, OR, AND, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN, LIKE, ILIKE, NOT LIKE, NOT ILIKE, REGEXP, IN, NOT IN, GLOBAL IN, GLOBAL NOT IN, MOD, DIV, IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, alias, AS. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 23.3.8.21)

ClickHouse doc clearly states that 'All variables used by a function must be specified in its parameter list'.

Oracle output is like this and I want to create this structure in ClickHouse,

`SELECT PercentTEST(3,8) FROM DUAL` returns 0.375
whereas
`SELECT PercentTEST(3,8,1) FROM DUAL` returns 0.4

Is there a workaround I can use?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION PercentTEST(num Float64, denom Float64, precision Nullable(Int8))
    -> Float64
    -> (
    if(isFinite(num / denom),
       if(isNotNull(precision), round((100 * num) / denom, precision), (100 * num) / denom),
       NULL)
);
```

**examples**

Without precision (similar to PercentTEST(3, 8) in Oracle)

`SELECT PercentTEST(3, 8, CAST(NULL AS Nullable(Int8))) AS result1`

With precision (similar to PercentTEST(3, 8, 1) in Oracle)

`SELECT PercentTEST(3, 8, 1) AS result2`

Comment: This doesn't get the job done, function must be able to work with 2 or 3 parameters. This way user still need to give 3 parameters.